# Microsoft Azure database admin user creation

Tags: mysql, sql, database, azure

I deployed azure MySQL 5.7 database in azure. I can't create another admin user with admin permission with the serveradmin login. When I tried below command GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sammy'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; I am getting error serveradmin@ip don't have enough permissions even though I am user server admin login. Is this because of Microsoft Azure database or is there any workaround to have user with maximum privileges.

Comment: Do you have a (_good_) reason for running MySQL 5.7? It's 2022 now... you're missing out on 15+ years of enhancements, stability, and ISO standards compliance.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the software requirements I should be using 5.7

Comment: MySQL 8+ and MariaDB both have excellent backwards-compatibility with 5.7 databases and clients - I strongly urge you to at least give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create another Admin Like user in MySql we use `Superuser` privilege to get all the access of MySql. But, On Azure Database for MySQL, the SUPER permission is not supported.

As suggested by **@Cameron Battagler** in [GRANT SUPER privilege on Azure Database for MySQL](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/grant-super-privilege-on-azure-database-for-mysql/ba-p/368905)

To work around this, you can create another admin level user with the same rights as the server admin

```
CREATE  USER  'new_master_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  'StrongPassword!';
GRANT  SELECT,  INSERT,  UPDATE,  DELETE,  CREATE,  DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS,  REFERENCES,  INDEX,  ALTER,  
SHOW DATABASES,  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES,  EXECUTE,  REPLICATION SLAVE,  REPLICATION CLIENT,  
CREATE  VIEW, SHOW VIEW,  CREATE ROUTINE,  ALTER ROUTINE,  CREATE  USER, EVENT,  
TRIGGER  ON  *.*  TO  'new_master_user'@'%'  WITH  GRANT  OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

USE sys;  
  
SHOW GRANTS FOR  'new_master_user'@'%';
```